# How to disable certain system calls for a given user?

Tags: linux, users, chroot, privileges

I am creating a web app similar to codepad and for each run-action my app copies a directory (`/home/radeks/voidptr/private/chroot-root`) to `/tmp/voidptr/[random-id]/chroot-root`. This chroot directory has a user that compiles and runs the code entered by the web app user. The problem is that I don't want the user to shut down the machine or use sockets for example.

Do I need to write a supervisor or can I simply set these permissions per user?

Answer (score 6):

Chroot only restricts filesystem access. If you have root permissions, a chroot is merely an inconvenience, not a secure confinement. Ordinary users can use sockets but not shut down the machine.

There are ways to restrict what users can do: capabilities, AppArmor, SELinux, … But by far the easiest way is to confine the webapp user to a virtual machine. You will easily be able to restrict things like network connectivity and resource usage. For your use case, a lightweight Linux-on-Linux vm technology seems best: something like [OpenVZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVZ), [user-mode Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_mode_Linux) or [Vserver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux-VServer).